# how to add a javascript function in jsp page by passing a hidden field variable to the function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a java script function:

```
function viewJunction(siteId, name{
}
```

I want to include this function in a jsp page in which siteId should pass through URL as query parameter.

Comment: Did my answer helped? do you still have an issue?

Comment: Yes,Yes. It did. I forgot to thank you. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get siteId from `request` assuming `siteIdParmeter` is the query parameter, and send it to function

```
<% String querySiteId = request.getParameter("siteIdParmeter");%>
viewJunction('<%=querySiteId%>', 'yourName');
```

to put inside input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="siteIdInput" name="siteIdInput" value="<%=querySiteId%>"/>
```

Comment: How to get siteId from URL as hidden field in jsp?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="siteIdInput" value="<%=querySiteId%>"/>